# How does ArrayObject in PHP work?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand this object but i can't figure out a simple fact. If count method shows public properties and the result is the number of keys in an array that was passed. In the case of an associative array when i try to access a key like a public property is not found. Maybe i misunderstood the interface.

```
//example
$currentDate = getdate();

//applying print_r() we can see the content
$objectDate = new ArrayObject();

//verifying the public properties- result is 11
$objectDate->count();

//but can't access keys like public properties
$objectDate->hours;
```

Comment: Minus, because this is "I'm too lazy to read docs" question.

Comment: Beside the fact that you've to use `['hours']`, you need a `$` in front of `objectDate->hours;`.

Comment: @RafałWalczak, did you read the docs? It's very unclear if you ask me. Upvoting because it's an interesting question and because Rafal is incorrect ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can access array entries as properties (`->`) by passing the `ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS` flag to the [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/class.arrayobject) constructor:

```
//example
$currentDate = getdate();
print_r($currentDate);

// create ArrayObject from array, make entries accessible as properties (read and write).
$objectDate = new ArrayObject($currentDate, ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);

// verifying the public methods - result is 11
print_r($objectDate->count());
print "\n";

// accessing entries like public properties
print_r($objectDate->hours);
```

Answer (score 2):

Such class implements `ArrayAccess` interface, so you can write:

```
$objectDate['hours']
```

With brackets notation, but not with arrow [`->`] one.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I see my problem now